# Bad encoding only on a half of page

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jsp, liferay

Hello I want to ask **what can be the source of problem with bad encoding** on the page.

This problem is very specific, because first part of page has good encoding and second part is broken.
Moreover it appears only in some scenarios, not allways.

The most weird thing is that starts to appear in the middle of one message and after this message, the rest of page has badly encoded characters.

This message is included in JSP with this part of code `<fmt:message key="the.text.wchich.makes.problems"/>`
Problem is not related to JSP, because bad encoding appears in the middle of message.

> Gratulujeme, toto číslo si môžete zarezervovať kliknutím na tlačidlo Pokračovať.

But sometimes it outputs as

> Gratulujeme, toto číslo si môžete zarezervovať kliknut�­m na tlaÄidlo PokraÄovaÅ¥.

or

> Gratulujeme, toto číslo si mô�¾ete zarezervovaÅ¥ kliknutÃ­m na tlaÄidlo PokraÄovaÅ¥.

So it is probably not the fault of badly entered text in database.

We are using **Liferay** 6.0, **jsp**, **spring**. Localized strings are stored in **Oracle 11g** database.

---

So, how is it possible that encoding begin to break in the middle of page?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify encoding in your JSPs as:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

You should be able to achieve the same result via [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) with `forceEncoding` parameter set and mapped to `*` path + `INCLUDE` dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one suggestion. Try to set locale from themeDisplay object.

<fmt:setLocale value="<%=themeDisplay.getLocale() >"/>

see if it helps to fmt:message to identify proper locale of message.

Note: This expects that you should have proper locale set for user or at portal level.